# How can I play .wma files with Music?

Tags: music, codec

[image: Screenshot of the Issue]

What codec is needed for me to play .wma files?

I can confirm that the file is not corrupted. I can play it in another app (VLC for example). I've already installed `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`

Comment: have you tried in other player?...

Comment: @Raven I do not wish to use any other player.

Comment: sorry--I am not recommending you to use other player...but I see `damaged file` in screenshot,thats why I am asking

Comment: @Ravan The file works yes!

Comment: please try this `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` --not sure but no harm done.

Comment: @Ravan Already installed bud!

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

This should solve any missing codecs problem.