# Noise won't import my music from my NTFS partition!

Tags: music, import

The message says: "Unable to import 2002 items from /home/santiago/Music
Music was unable to import 2002 items. The files may be damaged."

It imports some files but the rest it doesn't, the files are not corrupt.

I have elementary OS in a partition in my SSD along side Windows 10 in another partition. I use a 1TB NTFS hard disk for my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know which files were not imported? This could be an issue of missing codecs and a confusing error message (for example `.wma` instead of `.mp3` or `.ogg`).

You can try to install additional codecs to play some non-free media formats by installing [Restricted Extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) via Terminal as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

If that doesn't work you could also try to install additional gstreamer plugins.

See also: [How can I play .wma files with Music?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/how-can-i-play-wma-files-with-music)

Comment: Hi quassy! The [link](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/how-can-i-play-wma-files-with-music) you have provided  also installs `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, am I missing something?

Comment: No, that was just a reference as to how I came up with installing restricted extras.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was indeed a matter of missing codecs for the open format files were imported. However **I did not want to install** `ubuntu-restricted-extras` since those included several plugins I'd rather not install right now as flash and java.

I solved this by `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0` which installed a few libs and plugins.